# How to create a Spring Security Key for signing a JWT token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jjwt

I use `implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-api', version: '0.10.6'` as dependency.

I would like to create a JWT token as follows:

```
@Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
private Key secret;

JwtToken.builder().value(Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(createClaims(account))
                .setSubject(subject.toString())
                .setIssuedAt(Date.from(createdDateTime))
                .setExpiration(Date.from(expirationDateTime))
                .signWith(secret)
                .compact()).expiration(expirationDateTime.toString()).build()
```

I have used to provide a String in the `application.properties` and reference that key as shown above, but giving a String as a secretkey is deprecated. How should I create the Key secret?

Comment: why are you using `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api` instead of `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt'` version: '0.9.1' ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi because JJWT >= 0.10.0 split the dependencies to ensure proper plugin usage.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to convert the key string to a Java `Key` instance.

Is your key string Base64-encoded?  If so, do this:

```java
@Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
private String secret;

private Key getSigningKey() {
  byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(this.secret);
  return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}

JwtToken.builder().value(Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(createClaims(account))
                .setSubject(subject.toString())
                .setIssuedAt(Date.from(createdDateTime))
                .setExpiration(Date.from(expirationDateTime))
                .signWith(getSigningKey())
                .compact()).expiration(expirationDateTime.toString()).build()
```

If your key is not base64-encoded (and it probably should be, because if you're using a raw password for example, your key is probably incorrect or not well formed), you can do that via:

```java
private Key getSigningKey() {
  byte[] keyBytes = this.secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}
```

This second example is generally not recommended however because it likely means you have a poorly formed key.  A well-formed, secure-random key is not human-readable, so to store it as a string, the key bytes are usually base64 encoded first.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#jws-key-create) :

> If you want to generate a sufficiently strong SecretKey for use with the JWT HMAC-SHA algorithms, use the `Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm)` helper method:
>
> ```java
> SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256); //or HS384 or HS512
> ```
>
> Under the hood, JJWT uses the JCA provider's KeyGenerator to create a secure-random key with the correct minimum length for the given algorithm.
>
> If you have an existing HMAC SHA SecretKey's encoded byte array, you can use the `Keys.hmacShaKeyFor` helper method. For example:
>
> ```java
> byte[] keyBytes = getSigningKeyFromApplicationConfiguration();
> SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
> ```

Comment: Hello, i'm wondering why at the end of the token generation you added : expiration(expirationDateTime.toString()).build() after setting up setExpiration(Date.from(expirationDateTime))

Comment: @aurny2420289 it was just a copy-paste of the OP's question content.  What you're seeing is a chaining of their `JwtToken.builder().value(...)` API, which is not JJWT's API.  So I don't know what that class does.

Comment: @LesHazlewood , I'm using HS512 with ```Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);```. Once I generated the key where and how I could store the key for future validations when a request comes in with access_token generated with the method. Considering during validation of the request I should use the same secret . I use Spring boot 2.2.5. Any leads?

Comment: @Rajesh2389 ideally in one of your `@Configuration` classes, you convert the String into a `Key` instance and that would be a bean that you could reference elsewhere.  Spring will create only one instance of it if you reference it as a bean.

Answer (score 5):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149603/1808417) to a similar question.

```
//Generating a safe HS256 Secret key
SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);
String secretString = Encoders.BASE64.encode(key.getEncoded());
logger.info("Secret key: " + secretString);
```